# QtCore, QMutex class, lock function - stack overflow failure

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, stack-overflow

I have met a strange stackoverflow crash similar to the post:
[here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/39406/qtcore-qmutex-class-lock-function-stack-overflow-failure)

A QMutex is trying to lockit self recursively then causing crash...
The call stack is like this:

```
                ...(more repeat)
                Qt5Cored.dll!QBasicMutex::lockInternal(int timeout) Line 428     
                Qt5Cored.dll!QBasicMutex::lockInternal() Line 409    
                Qt5Cored.dll!QMutex::lock() Line 218     
                Qt5Cored.dll!QMutexLocker::QMutexLocker(QBasicMutex * m) Line 129    
                Qt5Cored.dll!A0x3737355e::`anonymous namespace'::Q_QGS_freelist::innerFunction() Line 566    
                Qt5Cored.dll!QGlobalStatic<QFreeList<QMutexPrivate,`anonymous namespace'::FreeListConstants>,&A0x3737355e::`anonymous namespace'::Q_QGS_freelist::innerFunction,A0x3737355e::A0x3737355e::Q_QGS_freelist::guard>::operator()() Line 129  
                Qt5Cored.dll!QMutexPrivate::allocate() Line 571  
                Qt5Cored.dll!QBasicMutex::lockInternal(int timeout) Line 428     
                Qt5Cored.dll!QBasicMutex::lockInternal() Line 409    
                Qt5Cored.dll!QMutex::lock() Line 218     
                Qt5Cored.dll!QMutexLocker::QMutexLocker(QBasicMutex * m) Line 129    
                Qt5Cored.dll!A0x3737355e::`anonymous namespace'::Q_QGS_freelist::innerFunction() Line 566    
                Qt5Cored.dll!QGlobalStatic<QFreeList<QMutexPrivate,`anonymous namespace'::FreeListConstants>,&A0x3737355e::`anonymous namespace'::Q_QGS_freelist::innerFunction,A0x3737355e::A0x3737355e::Q_QGS_freelist::guard>::operator()() Line 129  
                Qt5Cored.dll!QMutexPrivate::allocate() Line 571  
                Qt5Cored.dll!QBasicMutex::lockInternal(int timeout) Line 428     
                Qt5Cored.dll!QBasicMutex::lockInternal() Line 409    
                Qt5Cored.dll!QMutex::lock() Line 218     
                Qt5Cored.dll!QMutexLocker::QMutexLocker(QBasicMutex * m) Line 129    
                Qt5Cored.dll!A0x3737355e::`anonymous namespace'::Q_QGS_freelist::innerFunction() Line 566    
                Qt5Cored.dll!QGlobalStatic<QFreeList<QMutexPrivate,`anonymous namespace'::FreeListConstants>,&A0x3737355e::`anonymous namespace'::Q_QGS_freelist::innerFunction,A0x3737355e::A0x3737355e::Q_QGS_freelist::guard>::operator()() Line 129  
                Qt5Cored.dll!QMutexPrivate::allocate() Line 571  
                The maximum number of stack frames supported by Visual Studio has been exceeded.
```

I am using qt 5.4.1 on windows 8.1 system.

**And because the call stack's maximum frames has been exceeded, how could I check what function/call starts this endless recursion?**

Comment: Could you please show your code?

Answer (score 0):

[Bugreport](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-47554) available. I hope they will fix it soon.